# Already installed @react-native-async-storage/async-storage with expo install but deprication warning won't go away

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I have this warning in React Native Expo: `AsyncStorage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage`

I have installed `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` with `expo install` but the warning won't go away.

A search of my files shows no result for `AsyncStorage` What am I doing wrong, please advice

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "expo": "~43.0.2",
    "expo-firebase-recaptcha": "~2.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.1.0",
    "firebase": "^9.5.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-native-webview": "11.13.0"
  }
```

Comment: how do you import it and how you call it ?

Comment: I'm no using it anywhere in my app, I don't understand where the warning is coming from

Comment: Delete node_modules : rm -r node_modules. Then delete the folder expo and run yarn or npm install again

Comment: Done that, didn't help, I still have the warning

Comment: @DeonDazy do you mind listing the dependencies of your app?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the app dependencies

Answer (score 6):

Even though this is a problem with how the firebase package imports AsyncStorage internally, there is a workaround that will let you clear that warning for now, until firebase imports AsyncStorage correctly. The solution uses [getReactNativePersistence()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#getreactnativepersistence) method from the auth module.

We can use this method to pass the correct import of AsyncStorage, and then firebase won't have to import it from `react-native` internally, thus fixing this warning. Here is one way to do it:

```js
import { getApp, getApps, initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, initializeAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getReactNativePersistence } from 'firebase/auth/react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const firebaseConfig = {
   ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
let app;
let auth;
if (getApps().length < 1) {
  app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  auth = initializeAuth(app, {
    persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
  });
} else {
  app = getApp();
  auth = getAuth();
}

export { app, auth };
```

Adopted from: [Firebase Issue 1847#issuecomment-1041548028](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1847#issuecomment-1041548028)

Answer (score 1):

We might be facing the same type of issue :(
It is related to Firebase package. Here is a thread that discusses on potential solutions. I don't think it's fixed on Firebase's side unfortunately..

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1847

Comment: I suppose the solution is to not use Expo?

Comment: is you don't use Expo you'll be able to link your packages.. so maybe. However the issue comes from Firebase using a deprecated version of AsyncStorage. Hopefully they will upgrade it and it should fix the issue.